# return null textbox text in templateField inside of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

could not access textbox text in TemplateField

.aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PIN" AccessibleHeaderText="PIN">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPin" runat="server" Width="50px" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdPin.Rows)
        {
            TextBox lblDate = (TextBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("txtPin");
            string x = lblDate.Text;
        }
```

variable x is null.

Comment: on which event you are accessing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `TemplateFields` you have to use `FindControl` on the `GridViewRow` not the cell:

```
TextBox txtPin= (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtPin");
```

You always have to use `FindControl` on the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of the control you want to find. If the control is in a `GridViewRow` then that is it's `NamingContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  **RowDataBound** event

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
  // find and edit your control here
 // example 
  Label date = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
    }
```